# Кроссбраузерность HTML

Tags: html, css, кроссбраузерность

Делаю сайт, у меня в браузере было все ок, но когда я решил добавить блок с 4 картинками (код приложил) в Яндекс Браузере и IE они отображаются некорректно, что делать?

```css
#main-blocks { padding-top: 70px; }
#main-blocks h1 { text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 60px; }
#main-blocks .main-blocks-container { padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 100px; display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex; -webkit-box-pack: justify; -ms-flex-pack: justify; justify-content: space-between; width: 70%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }
#main-blocks .main-blocks-container .main-block { margin: 0 20px 0 20px; background-color: #f2f2f2; padding-bottom: 20px; border: 2px solid #d9d9d9; display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-box-direction: normal; -ms-flex-direction: column; flex-direction: column; -webkit-box-align: center; -ms-flex-align: center; align-items: center; }
#main-blocks .main-blocks-container .main-block h2 { font-size: 20px; }
#main-blocks .main-blocks-container .main-block img { width: 100%; }
#main-blocks .main-blocks-container .main-block p { font-size: 15px; }
#main-blocks .main-blocks-container .main-block button { display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 10; padding: 0 auto; border: none; background-color: #FFC312; color: #1e272e; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; -webkit-transition: 1s; transition: 1s; cursor: pointer; }
#main-blocks .main-blocks-container .main-block button:hover { color: #f2f2f2; background-color: #1e272e; }
#main-blocks .main-blocks-container .main-block:hover { border: 2px solid #FFC312; }
#main-blocks .main-blocks-container .main-block:hover button { display: block; }
```

```html
<section id="main-blocks">
  <h1>Мероприятия</h1>
  <div class="main-blocks-container">
   <div class="main-block">
    <button>Подробнее</button>
    <img src="img/blocks/1.png" alt="Фото">
    <h2>Мероприятие</h2>
    <p>Краткое описание мероприятия</p>
   </div>
   <!-- /.main-block -->
   <div class="main-block">
    <button>Подробнее</button>
    <img src="img/blocks/1.png" alt="Фото">
    <h2>Мероприятие</h2>
    <p>Краткое описание мероприятия</p>
   </div>
   <!-- /.main-block -->
   <div class="main-block">
    <button>Подробнее</button>
    <img src="img/blocks/1.png" alt="Фото">
    <h2>Мероприятие</h2>
    <p>Краткое описание мероприятия</p>
   </div>
   <!-- /.main-block -->
   <div class="main-block">
    <button>Подробнее</button>
    <img src="img/blocks/1.png" alt="Фото">
    <h2>Мероприятие</h2>
    <p>Краткое описание мероприятия</p>
   </div>
   <!-- /.main-block -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.main-blocks-container -->
 </section>
 <!-- /#main-blocks -->
```

Comment: Что значит некорректно?

Comment: @midia  там есть кнопка которая появляется по `hover` так вот в IE11 эта кнопка не по центру а в чём вопрос я не понял - голосуем за закрытие наверно

Comment: Еще раз говорю, у меня в двух браузерах все работает ОК, а в Яндекс Браузере и IE блоки становяться огромными и появляется горизонтальная полоса

Comment: добавь картинку как должно быть, и картинку. как сейчас в  IE11, чтобы сразу было понятно куда смотреть.

Comment: Пока я вижу, проблему с высотой картинки, и не установленными `left/top` для position:absolute